# Overriding default invalid email message in Grails

Tags: grails

How can I override default message when email address isn't valid.
I have following constraints:

```
constraints = {
  ...
  email blank:false, email:true
}
```

I was trying to display message in the messages.properties with different combinations:

domainName.email.error
domainName.email.invalid
domainName.email.email

I'm able to display message when email is blank. Obviously I was trying to restart grails after modification, but it still doesn't works.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: default.invalid.email.message=xyz  @ i18n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct message code to use for each constraint type can be found on the [user guide page for the relevant constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/email.html) (choose the constraint you need from the right hand column).  In the case of `email` it is

```
className.propertyName.email.invalid
```

so in your case

```
my.pkg.DomainClassName.email.email.invalid
```

(the first `email` being the property name and the second `email` being part of the `email.invalid` code).